# Авторазмер div по содержимому

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
<div class="dialog">
 <input type="text" value="Title" class="title">
 <input type="text" value="Message" class="message">
 <div class="button" style="text-align: center;">
  <input type="button" value="Yes"> <input type="button" value="No">
 </div>
/div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы блок **Dialog** автоматически растягивался под размер существующих `input`ов внутри.
Даже когда сами `input` изменяются пользователем.

Примечание:
`<input class="title">` - без переноса строк (`white-space: nowrap;`)
а `<input class="message">` - с переносом (`white-space: pre-wrap;`)

```
.dialog {display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;}
```

Перерыл всё, похожего не нашёл..

Comment: Я не совсем понял что именно вы хотите. Блок dialog и так растягивается по содержимому (т.к. у него структура такая и стилей, которые это нарушают я не вижу). Вопрос - как у вас "увеличивается" длинна/ширина блока ? Добавление новых инпутов ? Как расширяется родительский блок? В ширину или в высоту

Comment: Ах да, прошу прощения, не уточнил.. dialog имеет свойство `{display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;}`

Comment: А почему абсолютное позиционирование ? Да и странно это - блок даже в вашем случае (поставьте ему width:50%) будет расширяться если в него добавить новые элементы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".addBut").click(function() {
  $(".dialog").append("<input type='text' value='neweOne'/>");
})
```

```css
.dialog {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dialog">
  <input type="text" value="Title" class="title">
  <input type="text" value="Message" class="message">
  <div class="button" style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="button" class="addBut" value="Yes">
    <input type="button" value="No">
  </div>
</div>
```

Это не совсем ответ, просто попытка помочь. Как видно из примера - я использую тоже самое, что написали вы. Но блок спокойно расширяется в высоту, когда я добавляю в него новые инпуты (кнопка Yes). Поэтому просьба уточнить что именно не работает.

Comment: Внутри **div** находится несколько **input**ов, каждый из них может изменяться пользователем. Суть в том, чтобы заставить **div** растягиваться (по ширине\высоте), по размерам самих **input**ов

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Ну странное понятие, что у вас input увеличиваются в длинну ширину. Это тогда уже textarea что-ли =). Обычно для полей малого размера (1 строка) нет необходимости увеличивать их в дилнну/ширину - ведь они внутри себя смещаются так, что видно только последние n-символов. Если же инпут меняется - значит это уже multiline инпут и обычно называется как textarea. Можно попробовать поставить у инпута margin:10px, а у блока сделать как выше. Тогда если меняется инпут - будет увеличиваться блок (правда немного криво)